# Is it legal to sell money?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, currency

Is it legal to sell money for a profit in the United States? For example:

- Selling 100 rolls of pennies for $100 ($50 profit)
- Selling 1,000 rolls of quarters for $12,000
- Selling 1,000 dollar bills for $1,200
- etc

Would one violate any laws by doing so?

Comment: The second paragraph of [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/85896/18505) sketches a currency exchange fiction that is lawful and encompasses the transactions you outline here.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it’s legal

Any major city will have any number of coin and currency traders. Foreign exchange traders do this all the time.